# Is there a way to batch add date taken field to images?

Tags: metadata

I found my self with thousands of images that have lost the date taken attribute, but I do have the date taken in a html file.

(Basically all the images were put into a mysql table with the exif data extracted from the image into individual fields, I lost the originals)

Is there a software I can use to attribute a date taken to a filename in a batch action?

Comment: I suspect you won't find a pre-made tool which can read your HTML file, extract each date, determine the full file path to corresponding image file, and then modify the EXIF data of that file with the extracted date. If you're determined and persistent then you could write your own scripts or software tools to do this. If you're not thusly inclined then you could hire someone to create a tool for you. As always, it comes down to how much you want/need to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the date / time taken in [Lightroom](https://lightroom.adobe.com/) (main menu - Metadata - Edit Capture Time). You can apply it on multiple images, and you have three options

- shift the original date & time (when your camera clock was off)
- set a specific date & time
- set the date & time in exif to file creation date & time

If the Lightroom way is not an option for you (it is enough for me) try [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). It is a tool best left to more technically advanced users, and depending on your application might require you to write some code, but it definitely is capable of making the batch adjustment that you require.