# How to set a randomised creation date on multiple images on a specific year with Exiftool?

Tags: exiftool

I have multiple images that have been scanned from 6x4 prints, not knowing when the photo has been taken, most of the photos have not been taken on a particular event, but knows the year taken.

A one command to randomise the creation date on multiple JPG images on a specific year.

Comment: Why not just set them to Jan 1 of that year? See: [Is it possible to set the year instead of a complete creation date in a JPEG?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/19684)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to batch add date taken field to images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/90749/is-there-a-way-to-batch-add-date-taken-field-to-images)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to first set all files to the first second of the year you want to randomize
`exiftool -CreateDate="1985:1:1 0:0:0" /path/to/files/`

Then you could shift that time by a random number of days/hours/minutes/seconds like this
`exiftool "-CreateDate+<${Filename;$_=int(rand(365)).' ' .int(rand(24)).':'.int(rand(60)).':'.int(rand(60))}" /path/to/files`

Here, `Filename` is used as a placeholder to access exiftool's [Advanced formatting feature](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Advanced-formatting-feature), i.e. using direct Perl code, to get a random day, hour, minute and second to add to the base time.

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.  If this command is run under Unix/Mac, reverse any double/single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.

See also: [How can I incrementally date photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/)